# JavaScript: innerHTML outputs undefined, although console.log outputs the right value

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml

I am trying to make a calculator app in JS, and I am struggling with the sine and cosine functions. 
The line before

```
document.getElementByID("screenPar").innerHTML = result;
```

is

```
console.log(result);
```

, and in the console, the correct value shows up, however on the calculator's screen, it says undefined. My function:

```
function calcSin(){
    try{                                                    //Checks for syntax errors
        if(calcString[calcString.length-1] == "+" || calcString[calcString.length-1] == "-" || calcString[calcString.length-1] == "*" || calcString[calcString.length-1] == "/"){
            throw "Syntax Error"
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        document.getElementById("screenPar").innerHTML = err;
        return 1;
    }
    if(calcString[calcString.length-1] == "$"){             //If last character in string is '$', clears screen
        clearScreen();
        document.getElementById("screenPar").style.color = "black";
    }
    else{
        var evalRes = eval(calcString);
        console.log(evalRes + typeof evalRes);
        var result = Math.round(Math.sin(evalRes));
        console.log(result + typeof result);
        clearScreen();
        console.log(result);
        document.getElementById("screenPar").innerHTML = result;
    }
}
```

calcString is a string of the inputted expression, for instance "3*4*5". 
The console outputs the correct value, but innerHTML puts undefined in the paragraph.
I uploaded the code to a free hosting site: [brokenCalculator](http://brokencalculator.epizy.com). 
What am I missing?

Comment: Adding some breakpoints to your script showed that the `undefined` is not coming from `calcSin()` but from `addToCalcString()`. The problem is that you never return anything from `calcSin()` and so when `addToCalcString(char)` expects that argument, it works with `undefined`

Comment: I think you have a problem with sign '='. Function calcSin() works properly

Comment: Thank you very much, turns out I was using the wrong function in the html file.

Comment: This is one reason why it's considered a best practice to add the event listeners in the javascript file, rather than hard coding them into html. I think you would have caught the bug much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The function you've shown is fine. Something else replaces the `screenPar` value to `undefined`.

[image]

P.S. Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` unless you desire to add a text as an HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

`<button onclick="addToCalcString(calcSin())"...>`

Above onclick event you are calling function inside a function. When you click, 1st the **calcSin()** is getting called and below line is executing fine

```
document.getElementById("screenPar").innerHTML = result;
```

But after that the addToCalcString(char) is executing, in which calcString is undefined

```
document.getElementById("screenPar").innerHTML = calcString;
```

[image]